# Android Things on Lenovo Smart Display or Google Home Hub?

Tags: android, android-things, google-home

I know how to Create a **Smart Home Action** & trigger it via the Google Assistant.

Is it possible to run **Android Things OS** on Lenovo Smart Display or Google Home Hub and **Build & Run** a custom **Android App**??

Answer (score 1):

The smart displays made from companies like LG do run Android Things with an app that is the Assistant experience. However, as part of the consumer product, these smart displays disable ADB and other development tools, preventing you from being able to run custom software on these devices.

Comment: Is it possible to root the lenovo smart display?

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: I see i can download the source code https://smartsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/SMART/SMART-SPEAKER/LENOVO-SMART-DISPLAY/downloads/DS504927 so what can i do with it?

Comment: I wasn't aware the code was open source, but I don't think you can actually do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

adb root isn't usable.
Connect with usb type C and it runs.
Also adb shell is usable.
You must find the USB Type-C Slot.

To open Settings
monkey -p com.android.settings -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1

Comment: To run recovery mode: Power-off, then push an hold volume-up and power on, since some time it came into recovery-mode